# SQL Server encryption - rotate keys for PCI compliance

Tags: sql-server, encryption, pci-compliance

Good day,

Not sure if this question is better suited for SO or SF...

PCI compliance requires annual rotation of keys. The definition of "rotation of keys" that I keep coming across is decrypting your data, then re-encrypting with a new key. Really? Everyone out there is decrypting / encrypting all their encrypted data every year?

Currently, I've got 16 databases across 3 servers, with multiple tables in each database - and this will just continue to grow. Doing this manually introduces a huge opportunity for mistake, rendering my data unreadable. Yes, I could write something to do this...but is this really what everyone is doing? Can you recommend an affordable (subjective, I know) 3rd party tool?

I've seen some suggestions out there about "changing" the keys higher up in the hierarchy. We use the oft recommended hierarchy of Database Master Key encrypting a Certificate, which encrypts a Symmetric Key, which encrypts the data.

First, this doesn't seem to meet the definition of "rotating the keys". Second, even if I change the DMK or the Cert, this doesn't prevent the data from being decrypted with the same Symmetric Key that presumably *bad guy* has stolen / cracked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not decrypting and re-encrypting the whole database, just the symmetric key which is used to protect the data. Database is encrypted during this operation and it takes a couple of seconds.

Just test it, and write a simple script that will do it annually.

Remember to keep old keys forever, this is highly recommended. They may be required to e.g. restore old backups.